# Gather all selected elements in a form and their hidden inputs for submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Think polaroids on a table and you are asked to go through them and decide yes or no for each one. Yes being keep it, No being throw it out.

I need a element for each photo, to be displayed on a page, in some sort of tile fashion with two check boxes, (keep/discard). If a element has its child checkboxes checked yes, then some javascript somewhere gathers said boxes and puts the information into an array when the user clicks submit.

Each element will have hidden information about the photo being selected, like filename, location, and galleryID. If the javascript detects that the parent element div is selected, as signified by the checked yes box, also include that information in the array.

The end result of the array will be passed to a php file, which eventually print out the results in a csv file.

Can I be assisted in pointed into the right direction? Here is a my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9uZX7/3/

Here is my html:

```
<form onsubmit="">         
    <div class="imageTile" id="$filename-1">
        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/krawyh9"/><br>
       <input type="hidden" name="imageFilename" value="$filename-1">
       <input type="hidden" name="imageGalleryID" value="$galleryID-1">
        <label for="$filename-1">Keep</label>
       <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="$filename-1">
    </div>
 <br>
</form>
  <form onsubmit="">         
    <div class="imageTile" id="$filename-2">
        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/krawyh9"/><br>
       <input type="hidden" name="imageFilename" value="$filename-2">
       <input type="hidden" name="imageGalleryID" value="$galleryID-2">
        <label for="$filename-2">Keep</label>
       <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="$filename-2">
    </div>
 <br>
</form>
<div id="submit_buttons">
            <button type="reset">Reset</button>
            <button class="submit" type="submit" onclick="return false">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(".submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var checkedBoxes = $(".imageTile input:checkbox:checked")
    var resultSet = $(".imageTile input:hidden")
    for (var i=0; i<checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkedBoxes[i].checked) {
            $(resultSet).map(function(){
                   return $(this).val();
            }).get();
        }
    }// <----
    console.log(resultSet);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some modifications in your markup and JavaScript source:

HTML :

```
<form onsubmit="">         
  <div class="imageTile">
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/krawyh9"/><br>
    <input class="data" type="hidden" name="imageFilename" value="$filename-1">
    <input class="data" type="hidden" name="imageGalleryID" value="$galleryID-1">
    <label for="$filename-1">Keep</label>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="imageTile">
     <img src="http://tinyurl.com/krawyh9"/><br>
     <input class="data" type="hidden" name="imageFilename" value="$filename-2">
     <input class="data" type="hidden" name="imageGalleryID" value="$galleryID-2">
     <label for="$filename-2">Keep</label>
     <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div id="submit_buttons">
   <button type="reset">Reset</button>
   <input class="submit" type="submit" onclick="return false" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript :

```
$(".submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageTile = this.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('imageTile') ;
    var l = imageTile.length ;
    var data = [] ;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < l ; i++){
        if(imageTile[i].getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0].checked){
            var dat = imageTile[i].getElementsByClassName('data') ;
            console.log(dat) ;
            var ll = dat.length ;
            var datArr = [] ;
            for(var j = 0 ; j < ll ; j++){
              datArr.push([dat[j].attributes['name'].value, dat[j].attributes['value'].value]) ;
            }
            data.push(datArr) ;
        }
    }
    // Now 'data' is the array

    // dataString is a JSON representation of the array to send to the server
    var dataString = JSON.stringify(data) ;

    // Test
    console.log(data) ;
    console.log(dataString) ;

    /*
      Do something with your data here
    */
});
```

I haven't used jQuery more than the `$(".submit").click(function(event){` that you used.

There's no limitation of how many hidden inputs you have if the has className set as "data".

Comment: Thank you this was the key to what I was I missing!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you are looking for, but the following JSFiddle should help you on the selectors at least : http://jsfiddle.net/9uZX7/4/

```
$(".submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var divs = $(".imageTile:has(input:checkbox:checked) input:hidden");

    console.log(divs);
});
```

Do you need the hiddens to be grouped by div ?